# boost::function template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, functor

This program is designed to make a library to make it easy for C++ programmers to simulate circuits. Any feedback is appreciated. The error that I'm faced with puzzles me to no end.

wire.h file

```
template<typename S>
class wire
{
  public:
    // default constructor
    wire() : _s() {}

    // constructor with one parameter of type S
    wire(S s) : _s(&s) {}

    // converter to signal
    operator S() const { return *_s; }

    // resets the signal of the wire and return the signal
    S operator()(S s) { *_s = s; return s; }

  private:
    // pointer to signal being carried
    S *_s;
};

// functor, returns the negation of the negation of the signal of the wire as a wire
template<typename W>
struct ww_not
{
  W operator()(W w1) const { return ~w1; };
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include "wire.h"
typedef unsigned sig_type;
typedef wire<sig_type> wire_type;

main()
{
  sig_type s1(0x2), s2(0x3), s3(0x5), s4(0x7), s5(0xb), s6(0xc), s7(0x11);
  wire_type w1(s1), w2(s2), w3(s3), w4(s4), w5(s5), w6(s6), w7(s7);

  boost::function<wire_type (wire_type)> _not;
  //_not = &ww_not;
  // error missing template type
  _not = &ww_not<wire_type>;
  // error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
}
```

I've tried it several different ways, and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ww_not` is a functor class which needs to be instantiated, not a function with an address:

```
_not = ww_not<wire_type>();
```

Comment: Sometimes its easy to overlook the obvious.